# How to take id and make array from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arrayOfObj = [{id: 41, uid: "62d0e9d5-25d4"},
        {id: 42, uid: "62d0e9d5-25d4},
        {id: 43, uid: "62d0e9d5-25d4},
        {id: 44, uid: "62d0e9d5-25d4}];
```

expected result: a= [41,42,43];

Comment: Try this `const result = arrayOfObj.map(item => item.id);`

Comment: Why `44` is not in expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map&ved=2ahUKEwjCzqbMy_rgAhXWR30KHYEjCfUQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw12XNJirv8-3J2POqmbqwb2)

```
arrayOfObj.map(a=>a.id)
```

Comment: Simply dupevote?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript map function.
Read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map